# shell script: incorrect exit status of executed command

Tags: shell, exitstatus

I'd like to get exit status of the command passed as argument (to my sh script called `a.sh`).

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="$@"

echo "arg passed CMD: $CMD"
($CMD) >/dev/null 2>&1
res=$?
echo "exit status: $res"


CMD="echo aaa | grep -q zzz"

echo "in script CMD: $CMD"
($CMD) >/dev/null 2>&1
res=$?
echo "exit status: $res"
```

Once executing:

```
./a.sh 'echo aa | grep -q zzz'
arg passed CMD: echo aa | grep -q zzz
exit status: 0
in script CMD: echo aaa | grep -q zzz
exit status: 0
```

However if I run the command directly in shell I see:

```
 /bin/sh -c 'echo aa | grep -q zzz ; echo $?'
 1
```

How should my script look like, to get the correct status `1` instead of `0` of the executed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(CMD)` output were `aaa | grep -q zzz` that is why it return with exit 0. Just remove the redirection to /dev/null and you will see.
You could use eval to run commands from variables.

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="$@"

echo "arg passed CMD: $CMD"
eval $CMD >/dev/null 2>&1
res=$?
echo "exit status: $res"

CMD="echo aaa | grep -q zzz"

echo "in script CMD: $CMD"
eval $CMD >/dev/null 2>&1
res=$?
echo "exit status: $res"
```